# How to calculate input and output impedance of BJT Common-Emitter amplifier circuit

Tags: transistors, bjt, inverting-amplifier

Why is the input impedance not 260Ω in this circuit?

[image]

I calculated this impedance as follows:

\begin{align*}
I_B &= \dfrac{18.7V - 0.7V} {180kΩ} = 0.1mA 
\\[1 em]
r_{\pi} &= \dfrac{26mV}{0.1mA} = 260Ω
\\[1 em]
R_{in} &= \dfrac{180kΩ \cdot 260Ω}{180kΩ + 260Ω} = 259.6Ω
\\[1 em]
\end{align*}

Similar question for the output impedance, which I calculated to be:

\[
R_{out} = \dfrac{1kΩ \cdot 30kΩ} {1kΩ+30kΩ} = 968Ω
\]

**UPDATE:**  Bad answer key

Comment: I'm confused. You calculated 259.6 ohms, which is exactly what the answer key says. What's the problem?

Comment: I thought the answer key indicated that that was the Rout? Rout is last in the list of questions.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be the first time an answer key has a problem.

Comment: It is clearly a mismatch in the answer key. Your calculations are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm posting this as an answer so the question won't appear in the unanswered queue.*

Your calculations look good - the answer key must be mixed up.